# How to get the view count for product per storeview?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database

I'm currently getting the product views like this:

```
$product_views = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');
$product_views = $product_views->addViewsCount($fromDate->format('Y-m-d'), $toDate->format('Y-m-d'));
```

The collection `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` has two methods that are almost what I'm looking for: `addStoreFilter($store)` and `addStoreRestrictions($storeIds, $websiteIds)`.

However with these methods I can filter per store or website and not per storeview.

I know this should possible because you can see the views per storeview in Magento in Reports -> Products -> Most Viewed.